# three js drag and drop Uncaught TypeError

Tags: three.js

I have been trying to implement the drag and drop functionality found here...

http://www.smartjava.org/tjscb/07-animations-physics/07.08-drag-n-drop-object-around-scene.html

Whenever I customise it slightly and use it in my project I get the following..

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'point' of undefined"

whenever I try to drag a cube.  The rotation isn't occurring so it must be recognising that I'm trying to drag an object and it relates to this line of code..

"selectedObject.position.copy(intersects[0].point.sub(offset))"

I assumed since I am new to all of this that I had messed up, so I copied all of the code from the link above into a new page (so should be identical) and ran  it and I get the same thing (everything else works good)

Im probably missing something really stupid, I have searched for this and looked at other examples on how to achieve this, but since I was working my way through a book which explained everything I thought I would stick with this, and also it would be a good learning experience to figure out why its not working.  If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>07.08 - Drag and drop object around scene</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/threejs/three.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/threejs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style> 
  <script>

    // global variables
    var renderer;
    var scene;
    var camera;
    var cube;


    var control;
    var orbit;

    // used for drag and drop
    var plane;
    var selectedObject;
    var offset = new THREE.Vector3();
    var objects = [];

    // based on http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html
    function init() {

        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render, sets the background color and the size
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1.0);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2000, 2000, 18, 18), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x00ff00,
            opacity: 0.25,
            transparent: true
        }));
        plane.visible = false;
        scene.add(plane);

        var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
        dirLight.position.set(25, 23, 15);
        scene.add(dirLight);

        var dirLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
        dirLight2.position.set(-25, 23, 15);
        scene.add(dirLight2);

        for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            // create a cube and add to scene
            var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
            var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: Math.random() * 0xffffff});
            cubeMaterial.transparent = true;
            cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
            objects.push(cube);

            cube.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5 * 2;
            cube.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5 * 2;
            cube.scale.z = Math.random() + 0.5 * 2;

            cube.position.x = Math.random() * 50 - 25;
            cube.position.y = Math.random() * 50 - 25;
            cube.position.z = Math.random() * 50 - 25;

            cube.rotation.x = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            cube.rotation.y = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            cube.rotation.z = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            scene.add(cube);
        }

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = 35;
        camera.position.y = 35;
        camera.position.z = 53;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // add some controls so we can rotate
        orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // call the render function
        render();
    }


    function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        orbit.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    document.onmousemove = function (event) {
        // make sure we don't access anything else
        event.preventDefault();

        // get the mouse positions
        var mouse_x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        var mouse_y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        // get the 3D position and create a raycaster
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse_x, mouse_y, 0.5);
        vector.unproject(camera);
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position,
                vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

        // first check if we've already selected an object by clicking
        if (selectedObject) {
            // check the position where the plane is intersected
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
            // reposition the selectedobject based on the intersection with the plane
            selectedObject.position.copy(intersects[0].point.sub(offset));
        } else {
            // if we haven't selected an object, we check if we might need
            // to reposition our plane. We need to do this here, since
            // we need to have this position before the onmousedown
            // to calculate the offset.
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);

            if (intersects.length > 0) {
                // now reposition the plane to the selected objects position
                plane.position.copy(intersects[0].object.position);
                // and align with the camera.
                plane.lookAt(camera.position);

            }
        }
    };

    document.onmousedown = function (event) {

        // get the mouse positions
        var mouse_x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        var mouse_y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        // use the projector to check for intersections. First thing to do is unproject
        // the vector.
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse_x, mouse_y, 0.5);
        // we do this by using the unproject function which converts the 2D mouse
        // position to a 3D vector.
        vector.unproject(camera);

        // now we cast a ray using this vector and see what is hit.
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position,
                vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

        // intersects contains an array of objects that might have been hit
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            orbit.enabled = false;

            // the first one is the object we'll be moving around
            selectedObject = intersects[0].object;

            // and calculate the offset
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
            offset.copy(intersects[0].point).sub(plane.position);
        }
    };

    document.onmouseup = function (event) {
        orbit.enabled = true;
        selectedObject = null;
    }

    // calls the init function when the window is done loading.
    window.onload = init;

</script>
 </head>  
 <body>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'point' of undefined"
>   "selectedObject.position.copy(intersects[0].point.sub(offset))"

This means, `intersects[0]` is undefined which means the array `intersects` has no element (length = 0). You are using `raycasting` and it isn't working properly.

You should share your modified code so that we can check what is going wrong in your `raycasting`.

**Update:** I think your three.js version is greater than 71 while three.js version of this website is 71 or less. In the 72th version, there is an update in the `raycaster` -

> Ignore invisible objects. (@mrdoob, @tschw)

So, the problem is here -

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
```

Since the plane is invisible, the `intersectObject` is returning empty array.

**Workaround:** I found a workaround. You can remove the following line -

```
plane.visible = false;
```

You can hide the `material` of the plane instead in the following way -

```
plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2000, 2000, 18, 18), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xffff00,
                opacity: 0.50,
                transparent: true,
                visible: false
            }));
```

In this way, the `raycaster` will work properly and the plane will be invisible as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  To try and troubleshoot I am just trying to use the code from the above link i have copied what i have into my original question.  Any suggestions would be greatly appriciated

Comment: that's fantastic, and it worked a treat.  Thank you for your assistance...i did have a look at the change log, but didn't spot that (or more likely didn't know what I was looking for!).  Again, thanks for you help

Comment: problem in version of Three.js, Thanks